# Looping Macro Works on Step throw but fails on Auto-Run

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, autofilter

I am creating a Macro in theory to store a string as a variable, then using multiple loops to auto filter each column in each worksheet and delete all rows with the string inside it.

When hitting F8 to step through the Macro everything seems to work fine until the Macro ends. However as soon as I attempt to just hit the run button it only works on the tab that I have the initial cell selected that I want to put through the Macro.

Am running Excel 2016 if that makes any difference.

```
Sub Delete_Selection()

Dim Selection As Range
Dim Search As String
Dim ColumnCount As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim J As Integer

Set Selection = ActiveCell
Search = Selection

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(i)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
        ColumnCount = WS.Cells(2, WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            For J = 1 To ColumnCount
                On Error Resume Next
                .AutoFilter J, Search
                .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
                ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

                On Error GoTo 0
            Next J
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Cheers,

Comment: Do you really want/need `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` in the loop ??

Comment: You select a cell in the active worksheet but then you loop through the other worksheets without selecting a cell in each of them. 
Remove
Set Selection = ActiveCell
Search = Selection
and set Search variable to something within each worksheet after
With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to select a cell with a value and then loop through all of the worksheets, deleting rows with that value in any column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_Selection()

    Dim srch As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    srch = ActiveCell.Value2

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(i)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    .AutoFilter field:=j, Criteria1:=srch
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                            .EntireRow.Delete
                        End If
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter field:=j
                Next j
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That works like a charm thank you very much! Problem solved!